# Merge two dataframes and sum certain sums

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes:

**df1** such as:

```
COL1 COL2 Taxon 
A    B    Canis_lupus
C    D    Felis_catus 
E    F    Mus_musculus
G    H    Canidae
I    J    Felidae
K    L    Muridae
M    N    Canis_lupus_familiaris
```

**df2** such as:

```
COL3 Number Taxonomy
1    120    d__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Carnivora;f__Canidae;g__Canis;s__Canis_lupus
2    129    d__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Carnivora;f__Canidae;g__Canis;s__Canis_lupus_familiaris
3    134    d__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Carnivora;f__Felidae;g__Felis;s__Felis_catus
4    234    d__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Rodentia;f__Muridae;g__Mus;s__Mus_musculus
5    12     d__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Rodentia;f__Muridae;g__Rattus;s__Rattus_norgevigus
6    289    d__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Rodentia;f__Muridae;g__Rattus;s__Rattus_Rattus
```

and I would like to add a new column in df1 such as it should be the sum of the `df2["Number"]` column for each `df1["Taxon"]`.

**df1** such as:

```
COL1 COL2 Taxon                    Sum
A    B    Canis_lupus              120  # which is the sum of df2["Number"] for df2["Taxonomy"] == Canis_lupus
C    D    Felis_catus              134  # which is the sum of df2["Number"] for df2["Taxonomy"] == Felis_catus
E    F    Mus_musculus             234  # which is the sum of df2["Number"] for df2["Taxonomy"] == Mus_musculus
G    H    Canidae                  249  # which is the sum of df2["Number"] for df2["Taxonomy"] == Canidae
I    J    Felidae                  134  # which is the sum of df2["Number"] for df2["Taxonomy"] == Felidae
K    L    Muridae                  535  # which is the sum of df2["Number"] for df2["Taxonomy"] == Muridae
M    N    Canis_lupus_familiaris   129  # which is the sum of df2["Number"] for df2["Taxonomy"] == Canis_lupus_familiaris
```

does someone have an idea please?

Here are the data in Python format:

```
from io import StringIO

data = """COL1\tCOL2\tTaxon
A\tB\tCanis_lupus
C\tD\tFelis_catus
E\tF\tMus_musculus
G\tH\tCanidae
I\tJ\tFelidae
K\tL\tMuridae
M\tN\tCanis_lupus_familiaris"""

# Read the tab-separated data into a DataFrame
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\t')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'COL3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'Number': [120, 129, 134, 234, 12, 289],
                    'Taxonomy': ['d__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Carnivora;f__Canidae;g__Canis;s__Canis_lupus',
                                    'd__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Carnivora;f__Canidae;g__Canis;s__Canis_lupus_familiaris',
                                    'd__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Carnivora;f__Felidae;g__Felis;s__Felis_catus',
                                    'd__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Rodentia;f__Muridae;g__Mus;s__Mus_musculus',
                                    'd__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Rodentia;f__Muridae;g__Rattus;s__Rattus_norgevigus',
                                    'd__Eukaryota;p__Metazoera;c__tetrapoda;o__Rodentia;f__Muridae;g__Rattus;s__Rattus_Rattus']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df2["Taxonomy"] = df2["Taxonomy"].str.split(";")
df2 = df2.explode("Taxonomy")
df2["Taxonomy"] = df2["Taxonomy"].str.split("__").str[-1]
df2 = df2.groupby("Taxonomy")["Number"].sum()

df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on="Taxon", right_index=True)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
  COL1 COL2                   Taxon  Number
0    A    B             Canis_lupus     120
1    C    D             Felis_catus     134
2    E    F            Mus_musculus     234
3    G    H                 Canidae     249
4    I    J                 Felidae     134
5    K    L                 Muridae     535
6    M    N  Canis_lupus_familiaris     129
```